# Using settings.LANGUAGES with properly translated names using gettext()

Tags: python, django, translation, gettext

From Django Documentation:

> If you define a custom `LANGUAGES`
>   setting, it's OK to mark the languages
>   as translation  strings (as in the
>   default value displayed above) -- but
>   use a "dummy" `gettext()` function, not
>   the one in `django.utils.translation`.
>   You should never import 
>   `django.utils.translation` from within
>   your settings file, because that
>   module in  itself depends on the
>   settings, and that would cause a
>   circular import. The solution is to
>   use a "dummy" `gettext()` function.
>   Here's a sample settings file:
>
> `gettext = lambda s: s LANGUAGES = (`
>    `('de', gettext('German')),`
>    `('en', gettext('English')),` 
>   `)`
>
> With this arrangement, `django-admin.py
>   makemessages` will still find and mark
>   these  strings for translation, but
>   the translation won't happen at
>   runtime -- so you'll  have to remember
>   to wrap the languages in the real
>   `gettext()` in any code that uses 
>   `LANGUAGES` at runtime.

What does it exactly mean to wrap languages in real `gettext()`? How it should be called in the code?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) you can use `ugettext_lazy` in settings without causing circular imports:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = [
    ('de', _('German')),
    ('en', _('English')),
]
```

If you are using Django version 3.0 or higher then you should use `gettext_lazy` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly what it says: call gettext() on the language names when you actually use them or show them to the user:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext

for lang_code, lang_name in settings.LANGUAGES:
    translated_name = ugettext(lang_name)
    ...
```

(You should generally use ugettext rather than gettext, since all text in Django is unicode.)

To do the equivalent in a template, just use the {% blocktrans %} tag, which just calls ugettext behind the scenes:

```
{% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
  {% blocktrans %}{{ lang.1 }}{% endblocktrans %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This method is pretty stright forward and understandable. But in this case, whats the point of using a dummy wrapper in the settings.LANGUAGES? Since you have to wrap over every line in code anyway, whats the point of the wrapper function which is suggested by the tutorial.

Comment: Because when you run the gettext commandline tool over your source tree (probably via ./manage.py makemessages), you want it to recognize those strings as "needing translation" so it will add them to your PO file.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a comment and further explanation on the above Q&A.  I could not get my translations to work, read and re-read the docs, searched for hours online, and after reading this post I realized it came down to this:

I originally had:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('nl', 'Dutch'),
    )
```

Which would not work, then after reading this tried

```
ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
    ('nl', ugettext('Dutch')),
    )
```

Which made everything work...  and I just searched for this and it is in the doc's at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference, toward the bottom of this section...

Answer (score 0):

in Template you could just do the following:

```
{% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
      {% trans lang.1 %}
{% endfor %}
```