# django-translation: How to translate languages

Tags: django

The officual django doc suggest to write the following in the settings.py

```
ugettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
    ('de', ugettext('German')),
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
)
```

With this arrangement, django-admin.py makemessages will still find and mark these strings for translation, but the translation won't happen at runtime -- so you'll have to remember to wrap the languages in the real ugettext() in any code that uses LANGUAGES at runtime.

But, I fail to understand where to wrap the code with real translation tags?

e.g. my code in template is

```
<form id="locale_switcher" method="POST" action="{% url localeurl_change_locale %}">
      <label><b>{% trans "Language" %}:</b></label>
      <select name="locale" onchange="$('#locale_switcher').submit()">
            {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
            <option value="{{ lang.0 }}" {% ifequal lang.0 LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected="selected"{% endifequal %}>
          {{ lang.1 }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <noscript>
        <input type="submit" value="Set" />
  </noscript>
</form>
```

The solution suggested here: [Using settings.LANGUAGES with properly translated names using gettext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329278/using-settings-languages-with-properly-translated-names-using-gettext)

Shows empty select box with no text at all on any laguage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
// settings.py
ugettext = lambda s:s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('de', ugettext('German')),
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
)

// template
{% load i18n %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}

{% for LANGUAGE in LANGUAGES %}
    <p>{{ LANGUAGE.0 }} - {{ LANGUAGE.1 }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: For me it doesn't run  $ python manage.py runserver
Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing 'manage.py'
. It appears you've customized things.
You'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.
(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.
)

Comment: I think this line from django.utils.translation import ugettext is causing an error, as it's explained in docs

Comment: Just added the {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
 to my prev code and it works :-\

Comment: oh good, I though you were including it like the {% load i18n %} line somewhere..

Comment: According to docs: "You should never import django.utils.translation from within your settings file, because that module in itself depends on the settings, and that would cause a circular import." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//topics/i18n/deployment/

Comment: I agree @drozzy, I don't know why my edit suggestion was rejected as "incorrect", this is explicitly said in the django doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#std:setting-LANGUAGES I tested this solution with "ugettext = lambda s:s" and it works fine. I think it is important to provide users a valid solution.

Comment: I'm updating the answer with the lambda placeholder, I haven't tested it but I'll trust the comments on this ;)