# Django makemigrations : IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

When I attempt to run python3.8 makemigrations, I get the following :

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/gettext.py", line 436, in _parse
plural = v[1].split('plural=')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Upon detailed inspection by running python3.8 manage.py runserver , I observed the following:

```
2023-01-05 03:33:22,179 django.utils.autoreload INFO     Watching for file changes with StatReloader
2023-01-05 03:33:22,180 django.utils.autoreload DEBUG    Waiting for apps ready_event.
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 92, in <module>
    class Group(models.Model):
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 161, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1635, in contribute_to_class
    self.remote_field.through = create_many_to_many_intermediary_model(self, cls)
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1099, in create_many_to_many_intermediary_model
    'verbose_name': _('%(from)s-%(to)s relationship') % {'from': from_, 'to': to},
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 176, in __mod__
    return str(self) % rhs
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 140, in __text_cast
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 94, in gettext
    return _trans.gettext(message)
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 355, in gettext
    _default = _default or translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 268, in translation
    _translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 155, in __init__
    self._add_installed_apps_translations()
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 203, in _add_installed_apps_translations
    translation = self._new_gnu_trans(localedir)
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in _new_gnu_trans
    return gettext_module.translation(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/gettext.py", line 613, in translation
    t = _translations.setdefault(key, class_(fp))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/gettext.py", line 261, in __init__
    self._parse(fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/gettext.py", line 436, in _parse
    plural = v[1].split('plural=')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have checked everything in INSTALLED_APPS and it looks correct, since that is the only thing shows in the error trace.

Another error (seems unrelated) which is before the above error in the trace is :

```
botocore.utils DEBUG : Metadata service returned non-200 response with status code of 404 for url:http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
```

Ill be posting a separate question for the botocore error though I thought to put it here because I just felt to give the trace completely.

I have the following list langauges in settings.py which has mentions in the stack trace.

```py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('ar', _('Arabic')),
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
    ('ca', _('Catalan')),
    ('cs', _('Czech')),
    ('en-gb', _('British English')),
    ('el', _('Greek')),
    ('ko', _('Korean')),
    ('fi', _('Finnish')),
    ('pl', _('Polish')),
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('de', _('German')),
    ('nl', _('Dutch')),
    ('da', _('Danish')),
    ('hu', _('Hungarian')),
    ('sv', _('Swedish')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('it', _('Italian')),
    ('tr', _('Turkish')),
    ('pt', _('Portuguese')),
    ('pt-br', _('Brazilian Portuguese')),
    ('ro', _('Romanian')),
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
    ('sk', _('Slovak')),
    ('uk', _('Ukrainian')),
    ('zh-cn', _('Simplified Chinese')),
]
```

EDIT:
What I have tried based on the stack post here([Using settings.LANGUAGES with properly translated names using gettext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329278/using-settings-languages-with-properly-translated-names-using-gettext)) :

```html
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = [
('ar', _('Arabic')),
('ca', _('Catalan')),
('cs', _('Czech')),
('da', _('Danish')),
('de', _('German')),
('en', _('English')),
('en-gb', _('British English')),
('el', _('Greek')),
('es', _('Spanish')),
('fi', _('Finnish')),
('fr', _('French')),
('it', _('Italian')),
('ko', _('Korean')),
('nl', _('Dutch')),
('pl', _('Polish')),
('pt', _('Portuguese')),
('pt-br', _('Brazilian Portuguese')),
('ro', _('Romanian')),
('ru', _('Russian')),
('sk', _('Slovak')),
('uk', _('Ukrainian')),
('zh-cn', _('Simplified Chinese')),
]
```

Also tried:

```html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

gettext_noop = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ar', gettext_noop('Arabic')),
    ('ca', gettext_noop('Catalan')),
    ('cs', gettext_noop('Czech')),
    ('da', gettext_noop('Danish')),
    ('de', gettext_noop('German')),
    ('en', gettext_noop('English')),
    ('en-gb', gettext_noop('British English')),
    ('el', gettext_noop('Greek')),
    ('es', gettext_noop('Spanish')),
    ('fi', gettext_noop('Finnish')),
    ('fr', gettext_noop('French')),
    ('it', gettext_noop('Italian')),
    ('ko', gettext_noop('Korean')),
    ('nl', gettext_noop('Dutch')),
    ('pl', gettext_noop('Polish')),
    ('pt', gettext_noop('Portuguese')),
    ('pt-br', gettext_noop('Brazilian Portuguese')),
    ('ro', gettext_noop('Romanian')),
    ('ru', gettext_noop('Russian')),
    ('sk', gettext_noop('Slovak')),
    ('uk', gettext_noop('Ukrainian')),
    ('zh-cn', gettext_noop('Simplified Chinese')),
)
```

Error Persists !

Comment: Please show us your model definition. You're attempting to use translation somewhere in there, and the arguments to `gettext` are wrong.

Comment: Specifically show us your `Group` model. Also note that Stack snippets are for code runnable in a browser being HTML, CSS, JavaScript and not other things.

Comment: Sure. Let me check and get back.

Comment: @solarissmoke gettext is used at 133 places in my codebase. Do i need to look for a list ?

Comment: Oh wait, the `Group` model is in `django/contrib/auth/models.py`, did you change any of Django's code by any chance? Or did you monkey patch any of the translation stuff?

Comment: @solarissmoke added a list which points to languages in the stack trace.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Hello, Havent touched anything in the core. I believe its something to do with languages list in settings.py. Have updated the question.

Comment: Solved. Please check answer.

Comment: @solarissmoke I'm getting the same error again after doing a fresh install of my api. It is for sure the solution I proposed to the question I posted isn't full proof. The gettext_noop worked earlier but doesn't work now. Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using settings.LANGUAGES with properly translated names using gettext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329278/using-settings-languages-with-properly-translated-names-using-gettext)

Comment: ugettext_lazy is deprecated. I'm trying to understand the logic though.

Comment: @Earthling `ugettext_lazy` is replaced by: [gettext_lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy) I have added that to one of the answers

Comment: Yup. saw that. I have updated the question above as EDIT. Please check. Proposed solutions (one from the previous answer of mine which only worked temporarily , and one based on the post you shared).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat based on your answer, updating the question with solution. ALso tried it. Error persists. I'm running nuts.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat. Had a look at the updated question ? Any solutions that come to mind of what I should be doing ?

Comment: @Earthling is the error the same? please compare the traceback you get with the current traceback. If the error is different please ask a separate question.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat. I jusr re-ran just to confirm. Yup the error is exactly the same. I even deleted the docker volumes & images and created the containers from scratch. The same error appears.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat. Any idea of what could be done ?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Changed LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb' from LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
and the error disappeared. This is a line just above the list of LANGUAGES. Any idea why en-gb works and en doesnt ?

Answer (score 0):

I changed LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb' from LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en' and the error has disappeared. This is however a temporary solution because I still cant understand why 'en-gb' works and 'en' doesn't.

```py
# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'

# Includes all languages that have >50% coverage in Transifex
# Taken from Django's default setting for LANGUAGES
gettext_noop = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ar', gettext_noop('Arabic')),
    ('ca', gettext_noop('Catalan')),
    ('cs', gettext_noop('Czech')),
    ('da', gettext_noop('Danish')),
    ('de', gettext_noop('German')),
    ('en-gb', gettext_noop('British English')),
    ('el', gettext_noop('Greek')),
    ('es', gettext_noop('Spanish')),
    ('fi', gettext_noop('Finnish')),
    ('fr', gettext_noop('French')),
    ('it', gettext_noop('Italian')),
    ('ko', gettext_noop('Korean')),
    ('nl', gettext_noop('Dutch')),
    ('pl', gettext_noop('Polish')),
    ('pt', gettext_noop('Portuguese')),
    ('pt-br', gettext_noop('Brazilian Portuguese')),
    ('ro', gettext_noop('Romanian')),
    ('ru', gettext_noop('Russian')),
    ('sk', gettext_noop('Slovak')),
    ('uk', gettext_noop('Ukrainian')),
    ('zh-cn', gettext_noop('Simplified Chinese')),
)
```